# meshlab - save a transformation

Tags: save, meshlab

In Meshlab, I have two meshed surfaces that are the two components of one object. I can glue them by hand in the way I want. Yet I cannot see the way to save the result in one file to be used hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to run "Matrix: Freeze Current Matrix" to apply the transformation.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking how to merge two surfaces into one layer to save as a single layer file then use "Mesh Layer->Flatten Visible Layers" and ensure both layers are visible.

If you're asking how to save the transformation result then @TimAyres is correct - you'll need to use "Mesh Layer->Matrix: Freeze Current Matrix" first.